# End Date should be greater than Start Date in Yii Bootstrap datepickerRow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I am using Yii bootstraps datepickerRow : [Check this](http://yiibooster-3.clevertech.biz/widgets/forms_inputs/view/datepicker.html)

I want my end_date depending on start_date. i.e. end_date should be greater than start date. I've spent couple of hours on google to check whether any in-built solution available for it but didn't found any solution. Then after I written my own js code which's I think perfectly fine but its not working.

I've already achieved this thing with **Cjuidatepicker** and its booming.

[Check my working code for yii cjuidatepicker](http://creativecoders.blogspot.in/2013/11/end-date-should-be-greater-than-start.html)

But I don't know why its not working for yii bootstrap datepickerRow.

Any help would be appreciated.

Following is my code:

```
<?php
echo $form->datepickerRow(
        $identitycard, 'date_of_issue', array(
    'onChange' => 'setEndDate("passport_date_of_expiry", this)',
    'class' => "input-small",
    'labelOptions' => array('label' => 'Date of Issue <span class="required">*</span>'),
    'value' => $passportArr['date_of_issue'],
    'name' => 'passport[date_of_issue]',
    'readonly' => true,
    'options' => array(
        'autoclose' => true,
        'showAnim' => 'fold',
        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        'endDate' => '-infinity'
    ),
    'prepend' => '<i class="icon icon-calendar"></i>',
    'hint' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        )
);
echo $form->datepickerRow(
        $identitycard, 'date_of_expiry', array(
    'class' => "input-small",
    'labelOptions' => array('label' => 'Date of Expiry <span class="required">*</span>'),
    'value' => $passportArr['date_of_expiry'],
    'name' => 'passport[date_of_expiry]',
    'readonly' => true,
    'options' => array(
        'autoclose' => true,
        'showAnim' => 'fold',
        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    ),
    'prepend' => '<i class="icon icon-calendar"></i>',
    'hint' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        )
);
?>
```

// JS code

```
function setEndDate(id, date) {
    var selectedDate = $(date).val();
    $("#" + id).datepicker({
        startDate: selectedDate,
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, why wouldn't you do that inside the model rules? Any idea?

Comment: @PrabowoMurti: I want to do it through JS. Form is too big so it will be difficult for me to do it through model.

Comment: @Ultimate enable ajax validation

Comment: @YatinMistry: Form is too big and complex. enable ajax validate will disturb all the functionality. So want customized solution.

Comment: @Ultimate In your js function setEndDate, second parameter is not jQuery element (this in your parameter in datepickerRow). You can read input value as date.value; instead $(date).val();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your js function `setEndDate`, second parameter `date` is not jQuery element (`this` in your parameter in datepickerRow). It can't be read with jQuery selector.

In your function `setEndDate` you can read input value as `date.value;` instead `$(date).val();`

EDIT:

`setEndDate` function should work with this changes ([refer to plugin docs](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) related in source code of yiibooster, for example in my yii-booster installation : protected/components/bootstrap/assets/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js ):

```
function setEndDate(id, date) {
    $("#" + id).val(date.value);
    $("#" + id).datepicker('setStartDate' , date.value);
}
```